# XCode 5.1 -> Xcode schemes not visible on another machine

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, buildconfiguration, xcode-scheme

I created two `schemes` in a `project`. **Live** and **staging** and it's working fine for my `xcode` 5.0. But then I updated my `xcode` to 5.1. Now xcode shows schemes only on my system and when I send code to another machine in zip-format. It opens with only default scheme and Live & Staging schemes are not visible. Although it's showing `build configuration` that I made to differentiate between schemes. Any ideas for this problem?

Comment: You mean Xcode **5.0.2**, not **5.2**.

Comment: sorry I edited it. updated it to 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Open scheme editor (select scheme, near stop button -> Scheme Editor) and check `Shared` for schemes you want to share then commit new files or so

Comment: @trojanfoe, just preparing image)